# How to join elements at IGrouping by key?

Tags: c#, linq

I have IGrouping of Lists of Points like this:

```
Key 1
List<Point> p1
List<Point> p2

Key 2
List<Point> p3
List<Point> p4

Key 3
List<Point> p5
List<Point> p6
```

I need to convert this IGrouping to List of IEnumerable by key like this:

```
var result = new List<IEnumerable<Point>>(){p1.Concat(p2), p3.Concat(p4), p5.Concat(p6)};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like `SelectMany` case: `var result = source.SelectMany(group => group.SelectMany(list => list)).ToList();`

Comment: Any particular reason you want this as a `List` instead of the more intuitive `Dictionary`?

Comment: Your "IGrouping of Lists of Points" is not in valid C# code. Can you please give us the input data in valid C# code please?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample input, it looks like you have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, List<Point>>>`, not `IGrouping<T, List<Point>>`. The former is what you'd get from `IEnumerable<List<Point>>.GroupBy()`.

In that case, you may use:

```
var groups = /* TODO: Get the grouped elements */
var result = groups.Select(g => g.SelectMany(x => x)).ToList();
```

Here, `g.SelectMany(x => x)` will concatenate the lists that share the same key and `groups.Select()` will return the concatenated `IEnumerable`'s.

Comment: The way I read the question at the moment the type looks like `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, (List<Point> p1, List<Point> p2)>>`. It's just not clear as the OP didn't post the actual types nor valid input data as C# source. A better question would help clarify what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the key value to match the position of the elements in the final list. Thus, I'd suggest something like this:

```cs
var list = new List<IEnumerable<Point>>();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    list.Insert(
        index: group.Key, 
        item: group.SelectMany(x => x));
}
```

This will generate a potentially sparse list where the index of each entry corresponds to the group key, and the value at that position is the `IEnumerable` of points for that key value.

Comment: The way I read the question at the moment the type looks like `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, (List<Point> p1, List<Point> p2)>>`. It's just not clear as the OP didn't post the actual types nor valid input data as C# source. A better question would help clarify what the answer is.